# I want to include $(document).keydown(function (e) { in a js file, but I cannot make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

We are moving a large desktop application to a web application.  We are using kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC.    Some of the pages in this application use the kendo grid for data entry.   The grids are in a View.   We have developed a javascript file called iris.grid.js where most of the javascripts for the grids are in.   This reduces code duplication and maintenance.  We include the iris.grid.js in the View by

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/iris.grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is working great so far.   But now we want to add a `$(document).keydown(function (e) {....}` to the iris.grid.js.   If we put this `$(document).keydown(function (e) {....}` in the iris.grid.js this keydown event does not work.   If we put this `$(document).keydown(function (e) {....}` in the View it works perfectly.    We don't want to have to duplicate this code in every View.    I have put the `$(document).keydown(function (e) {....}` in the _Layout.cshtml file and it does not work there either.

So my question is how can we put this `$(document).keydown(function (e) {....}` in the iris.grid.js file and have it work for all Views where it is included? Or is there another method to accomplish the same result?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should show more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ['on'](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

```
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e){ 
       alert( "Pressed...");
    });
```